# Having trouble installing Pytorch on Windows

Tags: python, pytorch, conda

I have tried install pytorch with pip but there is no package fit for my environment. I use Python 3.11.2. Then I downloaded anaconda and installed pytorch successfully. However, when I imported torch in python, it said there is no such module.

I followed many tutorials by restart my laptop, created conda enviroment and install pytorch there. Nothing worked.

Anyone having similar problems?

Comment: can you try with python 3.10?

Comment: haven't downgraded to python 3.10 yet, I may try if nothing else works

Comment: Ah I misread the question at first. You probably have multiple python environments. To install packages with pip, always use “python -m pip install”. And replace python with whichever python you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

That's not clear for your problem. I think you may show the process of how you installed pytorch by conda.

You can use `conda list` `pip list` to show your package installed.

The problem in anaconda may be you install pytorch in your specific env, but when you open your ide (i.e. vscode, pycharm) you choose the base env. You may try run your code in your terminal by  `conda activate xxxx` then `python3` then `import torch`.

Comment: After conda list pip list, here is the message: usage: conda-script.py [-h] [-V] command ...
conda-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: list

I installed  with conda command line copy from pytorch website. Yes, I installed it in base environment and using VScode. I am new to this so I don't quite get the relationship between conda and python.